# How do I check that a *nix machine is online without ping?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ping

I have a bash script that uses rsync to backup files from two remote workstations (unix and linux) to a local hard drive. I want the script to check that the workstation is online before running rsync.
The easiest way I could think of is to use ping:

```
ping -s 1 -c 1 $SERVN > /dev/null; echo $?
```

This works fine for one workstation, but for security reasons, pinging is disabled on the other one. I tried nc and it also does not work. I also tried to "ping" the machine using ssh or rsync, but of course I get a password prompt, which kind of defies the purpose of doing this in the first place.
Anybody got any suggestion/idea?
thanks

Comment: nc -z <host> <port>

From http://stackoverflow.com/a/9463554/477035

Comment: Why don't you just run rsync?

Comment: That is bizarre, I had tried nc yesterday and it did not work (it just hang there fro several minutes), but now it seems to work. So I guess `nc -z $SERVN > /dev/null; echo $?` should do the job. or even without redirection to /dev/null.

Comment: [Disabling ping does not necessarily make your system/network more secure.](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/security-risk-of-ping)

Comment: I am not the sysadmin of that machine, but thanks, very useful link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nc -z $REMOTESERVER 22 
echo $?
```

If you are using SSH to do rsync that port should be open.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh $REMOTESERVER -o PasswordAuthentication=no
```

This should try to connect via SSH, but will not prompt for password, as that method is disabled by the option.

Caveat: this connection attempt may be counted as "unsuccessful login", and you could lockyourself out e.g. if you're using DenyHosts.

Comment: It seems that the easiest way it to use nc -z as suggested by RedGrittyBrick and Goblin, but thanks for this tip, it is going to be useful as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
hping $REMOTESERVER -S -p 22 -c 2 >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
```

Comment: and what does this do?